# cmd.exe /k switch

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I am trying to switch to a directory using cmd and then execute a batch file

e.g.

```
cmd /k cd "C:\myfolder"
startbatch.bat
```

I have also tried (without success)

```
cmd cd /k cd "C:\myfolder" | startbatch.bat
```

Although the first line (cmd /k) seems to run ok, but the second command is never run. I am using Vista as the OS

Comment: Is it possible the question above might be more relevant to the Super User Stack Exchange forum?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: ye, its not like us devs hit the shell ever, is it? /s

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
cmd /k "cd /d c:\myfolder && startbatch.bat"
```

Comment: What if the directory is called "c:\my folder\"  (notice the space) what do i do then?

Comment: @EvanLarsen that's a good question and i don't know the answer. let me know if you do.

Comment: Example for running cmder in IntelliJ, beware of the uppercase "K" : "cmd.exe" /K ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""

Comment: @EvanLarsen I just tested using a folder with a space in it and this worked fine.

Comment: Can you explain me what `/k` stands for?

Comment: @EvanLarsen : If u have a space in between the folder try to use the complete path within quotes

Comment: @Ender: Very late reply, I know, but see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Comment: Confirmed: A space in the folder path does not matter if the whole command is within double quotes, e.g. `cmd /k "cd /d c:\my folder with spaces\ && startbatch.bat"`

Comment: the command runs before changing to the required folder...

Answer (score 11):

ssg already posted correct answer. I would only add /d switch to `cd` command (eg. `cd /d drive:\directory`). This ensures the command works in case current directory is on different drive than the directory you want to cd to.

Comment: I incorporated this to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd cd /k "cd C:\myfolder; startbatch.bat"
```

or, why don't you run `cmd /k c:\myfolder\startbatch.bat`, and do `cd c:\myfolder` in the .bat file?

Comment: I don't think `;` can be used as command separator in Windows batch scripting. Typically `&` is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see an answer addressing this, so if anyone needs to access a directory that has space in its name, you can add additional quotes, for example

```
cmd.exe /K """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"" & powershell.exe"
```

---

From PowerShell you need to escape the quotes using the backquote `

```
cmd.exe /K "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat`" & powershell.exe"
```

Notice the escaped quotes

```
`"
```

inside the path string:

```
"`"C:\my path\`""
```

This will execute the proper command in `cmd`, i.e. the path surrounded with quotes which should work.

The example command above will initialise the MSVC developer command prompt and go back to PowerShell, inheriting the environment and giving access to the MSVC tools.

Comment: never heard of escaping with ` in batch.

Comment: True, I have updated the answer with correct example for `cmd`. The other example was for calling `cmd` from `powershell`. I hope the answer is clearer now.

Comment: I just started day one of Handmade Hero and the PowerShell example is exactly what I was looking for to inherit the environment variables set by vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&` or `&&` as commands separator in Windows.

Example:

```
cmd cd /K "cd C:\myfolder && startbatch.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

I give this as an answer because I saw this question in a comment and cannot comment yet.

`cmd /k "cd c:\myfolder & startbatch.bat"`

works, and if you have spaces:

`cmd /k "cd "c:\myfolder" & startbatch.bat"`

As I understand it, the command is passed to cmd as `"cd "c:\myfolder" & startbatch.bat"`, which is then broken down into `cd "c:\myfolder"` `&` `startbatch.bat` at which point the remaining `" "` takes care of the path as string.

You can also use `&&`, `|` and `||` depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: For those interested in exploring the difference between `&`, `&&`, `|` and `||`: http://www.chebucto.ns.ca/~ak621/DOS/DOS-Char.html