# Running multiple windows commands using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command

I have next to no knowledge of code so forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to run

`netsh winsock reset`

and

`netsh int ipv4 reset`

on a single command line. I tried using & and && but only the first command is executed.

Here's what I got from the other answers on here:

`cmd /K netsh winsock reset & netsh int ipv4 reset`

How can I get it to run the second command?

Comment: `cmd /k "command&command"`

Comment: Should be `/c` not `/k`.

Comment: Or: `cmd /K command ^& command` (or `cmd /C command ^& command` if you want the command window to close automatically afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cmd /K "netsh winsock reset & netsh int ipv4 reset"`
You can refer [here for more info](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).
Also [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714013/8013471) may be useful

Comment: Should be `/c` not `/k`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'll know to add those from now on. I was using `/k` so I could verify both commands worked, I'll switch it to `/c` now that I know they're both executed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Depending upon your need.    
    _/C_     Run Command and then terminate
    _/K_     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables

Comment: There are situations in which `/k` is preferable, but they're rare.  The OPs description does not suggest that this is one of them.

Comment: I don't think that, for OP, it matters anymore. It can be used based upon need. Since in problem _/K_ is used so the same is provided here.

Comment: If every time they run the command they wind up with an extra command shell, it matters.  (Not much, perhaps, but it's not ideal.)  Mind you, I'm unclear on why the OP is using `cmd` in the first place, since they say they're already on the command line.  `netsh winsock reset & netsh int ipv4 reset` should work perfectly well without the need for `cmd /c` *or* `cmd /k` ! :-)