# Create a task with task Scheduler to run cmd.exe with commands

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I created a task with the task scheduler in windows 10 to open cmd.exe. it ran successfully like this

[image: The output successfully achieved]

But I need to run some commands every time it opens something like this

[image]

and automatically runs this command.

this is important that it opens a command prompt first and then runs the command inside the command prompt automatically.

Comment: use `/k` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713960/cmd-exe-k-switch

Comment: Thank You so much it helped me a lot. 
but I have one more question what if I use hyper instead of cmd here, will it work the same way?

Comment: `hyper` is terminal emulator (console window itself), if you call `hyper` directly from scheduler consult documentation for `hyper` how to pass commands via command line

Comment: This does not appear to be about programming. It should perhaps belong on https://superuser.com, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/k` flag. See [cmd.exe /k switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713960/cmd-exe-k-switch).

If you don't need console window to stay after commands completed use `/c` flag. You can read more about them with `cmd /?`

Comment: @AsimImam idk, it was so long ago (10 years or more). Just try asking google your question (for example https://www.google.com/search?q=run+command+using+cmd.exe first link shows /k and /c switches)